# how it gets there from here

Tags: phrase-meaning

What do "there" and "here" refer to? It seems that "there" refers to Trump's bid to reverse the election results and "here" refers to a starting point of that bid. But this explanation doesn't sound natural to me. So I guess that "gets there from here" is perhaps an idiom to refer to "why things have become so". I am not sure.

What does "how it gets there from here" mean?

> On Monday, some Republicans expressed what appeared to be a grudging acknowledgment that Mr. Biden had prevailed. Senator Lindsey Graham of South Carolina, who had enthusiastically backed Mr. Trump’s bid to reverse his loss, told CNN that he had spoken with Mr. Biden and conveyed that he would work with him when possible. “It’s a very, very narrow path for the president,” Mr. Graham said of Mr. Trump. “I don’t see **how it gets there from here**, given what the Supreme Court did.”

> Source: [NYTimes](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/12/14/us/politics/biden-electoral-college.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You can't get there from here* is an idiom meaning "the method under discussion will not produce the desired outcome". Graham has slightly adapted the syntax to fit his previous sentence.

It's actually quite a nice use of the idiom, because Graham has already mentioned a *narrow path*. This makes the metaphorical landscape more vivid---the reader can imagine a narrow path from the Supreme Court (and their recent actions) to a future situation in which Trump remains president. The path can be imagined to be blocked or otherwise impassable.